# Convertir imagen almacenada en varbinary(max) a jpg

Tags: vb.net, vba, imagen

Os comento el problema.

Tengo una tabla en SQL 2014, la cual tiene un campo varbinary(max) que contiene los datos de una imagen (0x6956424F5277304B47676F414141414E5355684555674141415A4141414147514341594141414341767A624D4141414141584E535230494172733463365...).

Necesito recuperar ese registro y convertirlo en jpg o bmp para dejarlo en un directorio del pc....pero no logro dar con la solución...

Utilizo visual basic (visual studio 2012).

He probado varias maneras sugeridas incluso por chatGPT...pero no funcionan...

El últimos código que he intentado es:

```
                        ' Convertir datos binarios a imagen:

                        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numdoc", numdocToFind)
            connection.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = DirectCast(reader("IMG_FIRMA_CLI"), Byte())

                    ' Comprueba que los datos de la imagen no sean nulos
                    If imageBytes IsNot Nothing AndAlso imageBytes.Length > 0 Then
                        Dim imagePath As String = "C:\IMAGEN\imagen.BMP"


                        ' Convertir datos binarios a imagen
                        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageBytes)

                            Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)

                            ' Guardar la imagen en el directorio especificado como JPG
                            image.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                            Console.WriteLine("Imagen guardada exitosamente en " & imagePath)
                        End Using

                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("No se encontró una imagen para el registro con numdoc = " & numdocToFind)
                    End If
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("No se encontró un registro con numdoc = " & numdocToFind)
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using'
```

Pero en la sentencia  Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms), me da un error de que el parámetro no es válido.

Muchas gracias.